# Autoscroll to TOP with ui-router and Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've read so many different problems with this and none of the solution given seem to fit my use case.  I started by simply putting target="_top" on all my links, but that actually forces my app to reload which wont work.  I've also seen people say they use **autoscroll="true"** but that only seems to work if its within my **ui-view**.

The issue with this is that in my index.html file I have fixed nav and other static elements that are above my first ui-view.  This means when I go to other pages I lose the navigation as the page loads past those elements.  I've also tried putting this on the body with:

```
<body autoscroll="true">
</body>
```

This doesn't seem to do anything either.  So the question is, how can I make sure that new pages (new route changes from ui-router) result in starting at the top of the page? THANKS!

Answer (score 148, accepted):

If you want it to always scroll to 0 cross-browser, do nothing with autoscroll. Just place this your run block:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
   document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
});
```

Comment: Late to the party but love it !

Comment: You just made my day!

Comment: Works great. The only improvement I would recommend is to use `$document` service like this:
`$document[0].body.scrollTop = $document[0].documentElement.scrollTop = 0;`

Comment: From within an iFrame :
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
 window.parent.$("body").animate({scrollTop:100}, 'slow');
});

Comment: Works like a charm. No need for `autoscroll = true`. Just don't forget to inject `$document` in your `run` block like so. `.run(function($rootScope, $state, $document, $stateParams){
  $rootScope.$state = $state;
  $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
    $document[0].body.scrollTop = $document[0].documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
  }); 
}) `

Comment: You only need to set scrollTop on the element(s) that scroll. For example, you might just need to set it on the child of the <ui-view> element rather than document.body. That worked for me.

Answer (score 18):

[Using version 1.0.6](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/transition.transition-1.html#onsuccess), the `$stateChangeSuccess` event is deprecated in favor of the `$transitions` service. Here is the code I used to scroll to the top on every state change:

```
app.run(['$transitions', function ($transitions) {
    $transitions.onSuccess({}, function () {
        document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
    })
}]);
```

Comment: This is the up-to-date answer, the accepted one refers to an old uirouter release.

Comment: 5 SO topics and 20 answers later, this is the only working one. You should be up

Answer (score 12):

I had exactly the same problem, fixed navbar on route changes, page loading partially scrolled down the page.

I just added `autoscroll="false"` to `ui-view`, like so:

```
<div ui-view="main" autoscroll="false"></div>
```

**edit**

Just tested this method, bit of a dirty hack, but it works. Import angular services `$anchorScroll` & `$location` into the relevant controllers for ui-router `.state` config. Then use a `$watch` on ui-router `$stateParams` to call `$location.hash('top');` on route/state changes.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#hash

```
.controller('myCtrl', function ($location, $anchorScroll, $scope, $stateParams) {

    $scope.$watchCollection('$stateParams', function() {
       $location.hash('top');
       $anchorScroll();
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried this as well, but when I link to new routes it just shows up where the scroll left off from the previous page.  No luck :(

Comment: controllers get garbage collected on route changes, does the state/page you link to have a controller in the ui-router `.state` object?

Comment: Some of them do yes.  The odd thing is that is happens on all pages.

Comment: Just updated with another method using $location.hash();

Comment: when you are using them together like that, you do not need to import both. Just use $anchorScroll('top');

Answer (score 4):

There is an Angular service for this. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll

Sample Code:

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $anchorScroll) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function () {
        $anchorScroll();
    });

});
```

If you want to scroll to a specific element

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $anchorScroll) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function () {
       // set the location.hash to the id of
       // the element you wish to scroll to.
        $location.hash('bottom');

       // call $anchorScroll()
        $anchorScroll();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using ui-router.  My run looked like this:

```
.run(function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams){
  $rootScope.$state = $state;
  $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
    document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
  }); 
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to do a combination of the other two answers.

```
<div ui-view autoscroll="false"></div>
```

In combination with

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
});
```

**Note:** This is on v0.2.15 of ui-router

Answer (score 2):

Did the same thing as the excepted answer from @TaylorMac but in $locationChangeStart.

index.run.js:

```js
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function() {
   document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
});
```