# Click button to the top page doesnt work with AngularJS Router link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm having a problem trying to land on the top of a different page using AngularJS `ng-include` after clicking a button on the bottom of the footer page.

HTML (index.html)

```
<body>

<a name="top"></a>

<!-- header section -->
 <div ng-include="'views/header.html'"></div>

<!-- views section -->
<div ng-view></div>

<!-- footer section -->
<div ng-include="'views/footer.html'"></div>

</body>
```

HTML (footer.html) `href="#!request"` is to load the request page - that works OK, but did not land to the top of the request page.

```
<div class="cont3">
    <div><a href="#!request" class="footer-link" id="myBtn">Request an interpreter</a></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ($('#myBtn').length) {
    var scrollTrigger = 100, 
    backToTop = function () {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop > scrollTrigger) {
            $('#myBtn').addClass('show');
        } else {
            $('#myBtn').removeClass('show');
        }
    };
    backToTop();
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        backToTop();
    });
    $('#myBtn').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 100);
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should really make a choice: either you want to use jQuery (which will break your app more than help), or you can use Angular and take advantage of all the help Angular offers. You should be using `ui-sref` for your links. It will simplify your life with ui-router.

Comment: The problem is you are missing the `/` after `#!`

Comment: I was told to remove the `/` and it worked for me, but just that when I click the button on the footer and it landed partially on the other page. I see your point about choosing 'ui-sref' to keep the Angular app. I'm going to see if that works. Thanks!

Comment: In that case you should read about hash on-page links: ["A URL fragment is a name preceded by a hash mark (#), which specifies an internal target location (an ID of an HTML element) within the current document."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) and differentiate that against Google's (DEPRECATED) idea of [Hashbang and HTML5 Modes](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.14/docs/guide/$location). No current version of Angular (including AngularJS) advocates the use of Hashbang URLs.

Answer (score -2):

As Randy commented the main problem you are facing is not how to acutoscroll but using two frameworks (AngularJS & jQuery) which can accomplish really similar things. There's really little you can do with jQuery that can't be done using Angular.

Check this post's answers for a few ways to always auto-scroll to top on navigation events: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27430246/3877743

Googd luck!