# Auto scroll to top in angularjs with UI View

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, autoscroll

I am stuck in a code block where I have to send the page to the top.
Condition is when user click on a link it travel to the next page but th problem is page will load from where previous page left off.
I found some suggestion from this link 
[Autoscroll to TOP with ui-router and Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26444418/autoscroll-to-top-with-ui-router-and-angularjs)
but it is not working.

Here is my code(have a look)

```
function runBlock($rootScope, MetaTags) {
$rootScope.MetaTags = MetaTags;
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function() {
   document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
});}
angular
.module('mainApp')
.run(['$rootScope', 'MetaTags', runBlock]);
```

Can someone help me out, thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try `$anchorScroll()` . It would be more easy to help you if you can create a demo on plunkr.com .

Comment: I used every solution I found on the Internet

Comment: Can u create basic demo  on https://plnkr.co/edit/